# Вызвать конструктор экземпляра два или более раз

Tags: c#, ооп

Возможно ли вызвать конструктор следующего класса:

```
public class Employee
{
    private Action _action;

    public Employee(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public Employee()
    {
        _action = RoutineWork;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        _action?.Invoke();
    }

    private void RoutineWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performs routine work");
    }
}
```

два или более раз?

То есть, вызвался конструктор без аргументов:

```
Employee _employee = new Employee();
```

А теперь у этого экземпляра возможно ли вызвать конструктор с аргументом `Action action`?

P.S. Вопрос задан чисто из любопытства.

Comment: Можно, никто не запрещает. Можно и десять, и двадцать. А можно и ноль.

Comment: 1 экземпляр класса = 1 вызов конструктора (при условии, что конструкторы не вызывают друг друга)

Comment: Непонятно, что имеется в виду всё-таки. Конструктор вызывается не "вручную", а автоматически при создании экземпляра класса. Можете создать несколько экземпляров класса. Или что вы хотите?

Comment: @iiKuzmychov к одному объекту можно два раза конструктор вызвать, `var obj = new MyClass()`, а затем `obj = new MyClass(params)`, вот и два раза вызвали

Comment: @Kalmankantaja это будет 2 разных экземпляра, а я говорил про один

Comment: `Employee _employee = new Emplyee();` Вызвался констурктор без аргументов. А теперь у этого экземпляра возможно ли вызвать конструктор с аргументом `Action action`?

Comment: Зачем? Это 1) выглядит странно; 2) нельзя так сделать. Возьмите Fluent builder паттерн, если у вас есть задача создавать объект поэтапно.

Comment: Конструктор нельзя вызвать более одного раза. Сделайте обычный метод с нужным функционалом и вызывайте его если нужно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> вызвался конструктор без аргументов: `Employee _employee = new Employee();` А теперь у этого экземпляра возможно ли вызвать конструктор с аргументом `Action action`?

Не представляю зачем такое может понадобиться. Если только ради эксперимента. Сделать это через рефлексию у меня не получилось, но через IL это проделать можно.

Возьмём вот такой код за основу:

```
var empl = new Employee();
empl.Work();
var empl2 = Reconstruct(empl, () => Console.WriteLine("Performs alternative work"));
empl2.Work();
Console.WriteLine($"Same instance: {object.ReferenceEquals(empl, empl2)}");

static Employee Reconstruct(Employee empl, Action action)
{
    empl = new Employee(action);
    return empl;
}
```

Если запустить код как есть:

```
Performs routine work
Performs alternative work
Same instance: False
```

то, естественно, получаем *False* в последней строке, т.к. создаётся новый экземпляр.

Теперь нужно изменить код метода *Reconstruct* так, чтобы вместо создания объекта

```
empl = new Employee(action);
```

просто происходил бы вызов метода конструктора для уже существующего экземпляра, что-то типа

```
empl..ctor(action);
```

В C#, к сожалению (или к счастью), нет средств, чтобы это выразить. Но в CIL такая возможность есть.

Берём IL-код метода *Reconstruct*. Вот так он выглядит:

```
// empl = new Employee(action);
IL_0000: ldarg.1
IL_0001: newobj instance void Employee::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Action)
IL_0006: starg.s empl
// return empl;
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: ret
```

И вносим необходимые правки, чтобы, опять же, вместо конструирования экземпляра

```
newobj instance void Employee::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Action)
```

происходил бы вызов метода конструктора для уже существующего экземпляра

```
call instance void Employee::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Action)
```

Вот такой незатейливый код, с использованием библиотеки [InlineIL.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InlineIL.Fody), я составил:

```
using InlineIL;

static Employee Reconstruct(Employee empl, Action action)
{
    IL.Emit.Ldarg_0();
    IL.Emit.Ldarg_1();
    IL.Emit.Call(new MethodRef(typeof(Employee), ".ctor", new TypeRef[] { typeof(Action) }));
    return empl;
}
```

Тело метода компилируется в следующий IL-код:

```
// empl..ctor(action);
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: call instance void Employee::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Action)
// return empl;
IL_0007: ldarg.0
IL_0008: ret
```

То, что надо. Запускаем изменённый код, и получаем:

```
Performs routine work
Performs alternative work
Same instance: True               <--- !!!
```

т.е. один и тот же экземпляр сделал два разных действия.

---

Возникает закономерный вопрос. А есть ли разница с нормальным вызовом конструктора, кроме того, что не происходит выделение памяти?

Да, разница есть, ведь согласно спецификации CLI (ECMA-335):

> **III.4.21 newobj – create a new object**
>
> ...
>
> The `newobj` instruction allocates a new instance of the class associated with *ctor* and initializes all the fields in the new instance to 0 (of the proper type) or *null* as appropriate. It then calls the constructor with the given arguments along with the newly created instance. ...
>
> ...

инструкция `newobj` должна создать (выделить память под) новый экземпляр класса, **проинициализировать все его поля нулями** и, затем, вызвать метод конструктора для вновь созданного экземпляра.

Поэтому, даже без учёта выделения памяти, повторный вызов метода конструктора не является эквивалентным нормальному вызову конструктора, т.к. не происходит сброс состояния экземпляра. Это можно видеть на следующем примере.

Добавим в определение класса *Employee* флаг-свойство, которое будет сообщать о том, выполнялся ли метод *Work*:

```
public class Employee
{
    ...
    public bool IsWorkPerformed { get; private set; } = false;

    public void Work()
    {
        IsWorkPerformed = true;
        _action?.Invoke();
    }
    ...
}
```

И выведем состояние флага после конструирования, "реконструирования" и выполнения метода *Work*:

```
var empl = new Employee();
Console.WriteLine($"Is work performed: {empl.IsWorkPerformed}");
empl.Work();
Console.WriteLine($"Is work performed: {empl.IsWorkPerformed}");
var act = () => Console.WriteLine("Performs alternative work");
var empl2 = Reconstruct(empl, act);
Console.WriteLine($"Is work performed: {empl2.IsWorkPerformed}");
empl2.Work();
Console.WriteLine($"Is work performed: {empl2.IsWorkPerformed}");
Console.WriteLine($"Same instance: {object.ReferenceEquals(empl, empl2)}");
```

Если запустить теперь неизменённый код, то всё выглядит нормально:

```
Is work performed: False
Performs routine work
Is work performed: True
Is work performed: False
Performs alternative work
Is work performed: True
Same instance: False
```

состояние флагов - *False* после создания экземпляра, и *True* после вызова метода *Work*.

При выполнении же изменённого кода получаем *True* после "реконструкции"

```
Is work performed: False
Performs routine work
Is work performed: True
Is work performed: True          <--- !!! Bad state !!!
Performs alternative work
Is work performed: True
Same instance: True
```

т.к. состояние существующего экземпляра частично сохранилось.

---

И последний момент. Строго говоря, повторный вызов конструктора нарушает одно из правил соответствия общеязыковой спецификации (т.н. *CLS compliance*). Вот соответствующее правило:

> **I.8.9.6.6 Constructors**
>
> ...
>
> **CLS Rule 22**: An object constructor shall not be called except as part of the creation of an object, and an object shall not be initialized twice.
>
> ...

которое говорит о том, что конструктор объекта должен вызываться только в процессе создания объекта.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Это именно тот ответ который я хотел увидеть.

Comment: Ответ невероятный, еще больше захотелось в CIL копаться =)

Comment: По-идее таким же образом можно нарушить какие-нибудь другие подобные спецификации просто делая call, не только с конструктором, думаю если подумать то можно найти что-нибудь, может как-нибудь можно провернуть с box/unbox, или вместо вызова `call ctor` дёрнуть `ldnull`, тогда по идее из метода вернётся null (не уверен). Или вместо `call ctor` дёрнуть `newarr`. Хотя скорее всего будет ошибка на стадии выполнения

Comment: @Kalmankantaja, `newarr` или что-то совсем не валидное, думаю runtime выбросит исключение. Я ещё пытался обнулить состояние с помощью `initobj`, но здесь он просто делает `empl = null`. А CLS-compliance вообще вещь опциональная. Т.е. если мы делаем сборку на C# и хотим, чтобы она без проблем могла использоваться в F#, то стоит об этом думать. Но даже и тогда правила соответствия применяются только к вещам выставляемым из сборки наружу. Упаковка значимых типов, кстати, нарушает compliance, или даже такие простые вещи как использование беззнаковых целых - _ushort_, _uint_ (кроме _byte_).

Answer (score 1):

Нет нельзя.

> 1 экземпляр класса = 1 вызов конструктора (при условии, что конструкторы не вызывают друг друга) –
> iiKuzmychov